# Quasi-experiment analysis

Tags: r, difference-in-difference, random-allocation, identifiability, regression-discontinuity

I have 5-year sales information from a grocery store in Canada. I want to check the effect of an online campaign that happened in 2017 on food sales. My treatment group is people living in urban areas.
My first question is whether this would be considered a quasi-experiment or not? I ask this because I did not cause the intervention and it is caused by others.
Besides, should I use the DiD model or RD? which one is the best choice. I've already done the analysis by difference-in-difference but I am uncertain if regression discontinuity will work better. Should I do any pre-analysis steps in r for identification strategy?